# Function to count the number of cells in a column that contain a string

Tags: string, google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula

This seems so basic but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

My inclination is to

1. Have an array that is a subset of the original column but only shows
   the cells containing "string"
2. Then, I would put that array in a count function that will spit out
   the length of the array. Voila.

Side note: the cells are a decent length so I'm not looking for an exact match of that string but for it to be contained somewhere therein.

Answer (score 3):

I think the [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=25273&page=table.cs&tab=1240293) function would be sufficient for this task.

```
=COUNTIF(A:A;"*string*")
```